# Import a JSON query from investing.com

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I've trying this for several days and I'm not able to load the data displayed below the graph in https://es.investing.com/equities/facebook-inc

IMPORTHTML does not work because these fields are the response from a JSON query. I've used Chrome Dev Tools to save the result in a HAR file and found one of the fields "Retorno un año", but I am not able to automatize the query (curl cmd only returns the .js source code, not the response, it was the first time that I used it...):

[image]
Any ideas about how to import these fields into a Google Docs Spreadsheet?

P.S.: I can't paste the commands due to my low reputation (no more than 1 URL allowed), sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull in all those fields using importxml instead of importhtml:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://es.investing.com/equities/facebook-inc","//*[@class='clear overviewDataTable']/*")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! it works, it will be really helpful, thank you so much :). Best Regards.